# Xcode Network Extensions Account

Tags: macos, networking, xcode, firewall

I am currently having trouble to build the simple firewall sample code
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/filtering_network_traffic
for Network Extensions , I saw it's not possible to use NE with a personnal team account but I have an iOS University one with this account I was not able to build it aswell.

Errors:

- No profiles for 'com.example.apple-samplecode.SimpleFirewall8FTGRDPGFZ' were found
- Personal development teams, including ....., do not support the System Extension and Network Extensions capabilities.

Do university account work for Network Extensions ?
And how to build it ?

Thank you

Comment: We can answer the “which account can build question” on Ask a different but the how to build portion belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have some news on the NE,
actually the iOS University account does not support the NE for macOS in order to compile the Simple Firewall sample code you need to sign it on your account but in the IOS University as a student you can't sign an app only the admin can and if you try you will have a permission error.

The only way to use NE is a "developper" account with the membership fees.

So I will transfer my idea with mullvad/pfctl or on linux with the BPF and redbpf for rust.

Comment: Thanks for mullvad/pfctl and redbpf ideas! Have you had any trouble implementing any of those two variants?